# How to get the message sender UUID/metadata from pubnub history?

Tags: pubnub

I want to know who sent the messages when retrieved from the pubnub.history!

pubnub.history() only returns timetoken and the message.

Answer (score 3):

## PubNub Sender UUID: realtime vs history

The sender (publisher) UUID is provided in the message you receive in realtime as a subscriber, but PubNub only stores the actual `message` you published along with any `meta` data that provided:

[PubNub JavaScript SDK publish docs sample code](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-publish-and-subscribe#publish_basic_usage)

```js
pubnub.publish(
    {
        channel: 'my_channel',
        message: { 
            such: 'object'
        },
        meta: { 
            "cool": "meta"
        }
    }, 
    function (status, response) {
        if (status.error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(status)
        } else {
            console.log("message Published w/ timetoken", response.timetoken)
        }
    }
);
```

Best practice would be to add the publisher's UUID to the `meta` parameter which will not only allow you to get this value using `history` API, but you can also use it to filter out messages that the client has sent ([don't receive your own messages using Stream Filter](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/stream-filtering-tutorial)).

Comment: I have tried that before, but only entry and timetoken I get !

Comment: Logs, I must see. Troubleshoot, I will. ;) If you can [enable PubNub client logging and reproduce the issue and send us the log results](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-troubleshooting-guide), I can probably find the root cause. You can [send to PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and I will post back resolution here. Be sure to include this SO link when you contact us at support.

Comment: Also, I think you are not understanding the different between the message and the metadata.

Comment: I understand the difference, I'm currently using the metadata a lot, but It doesn't work in the history, anyway, I managed to get around this issue.

Comment: Sure thing. Would like to know the solution/workaround and please file any issues with metadata not being stored or accessible in PubNub Storage with PubNub Support so we can fix anything that is not working as expected.